# how to view the data in hidden directory in linux

Tags: linux

One the hidden directory(.) having the more size. i want to check which are all the files residing that directory. Can any one please help me.

```
   2.6G    .
```

I have tried to access the directory, but can't.

Comment: That's not a hidden directory. That's the current directory.

Comment: Ok thank you. How can I access that. i tried with cd . but still am in current directory only.

Comment: You're already in the current directory. You've already accessed it.

Comment: Yes, understood now. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

After you `cd` into the directory, run: `ls  -la`

It is the `-a` flag in particular that you need. The `l` just makes it more readable as a list.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
ls -lah .
```

This command does not show size of directory which are inside your direcoty.